# SSH command outputting to terminal but not console log in Electron

Tags: node.js, ssh, electron

I'm trying to connect to a machine with SSH via Node JS and Electron. Here is my example:

```
var command = spawn('ssh', ['-i', '.ssh/mykey', 'ubuntu' + '@' + 'blah.blah.blah']);
command.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`out ${data}`);
});
command.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`err ${data}`);
});
```

I am getting all messages output to stdout and stderr, except those that require user input. For example, when connecting to a machine the first time, the following message won't print to the dev tools console.log, but prints to my debugging terminal window instead:

```
The authenticity of host 'blah.blah.blah (10.10.10.10)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 
a4:d9:a4:d9:a4:d9a4:d9:a4:d9a4:d9a4:d9a4:d9a4:d9a4:d9.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I know there are options such as this

```
-o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

however, I don't want to disable this security feature. I still want the prompt and the option for the user to say (yes/no)

Any idea how I can get this type of message into the console log of my electron application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this event by adding the verbose tag (-v) to the ssh spawn command

However after making this multi operating system independent, using the npm ssh2 module in node was much easier and handles steps like these automatically